# More partitions same throughput in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apachebench

I have an application in which I use apache Kafka and I try to do some tests.
My application consists of: 
**a)** a service which receive `http requests` and sends the messages in Kafka. **b)** a `mongoDB` which receives the messages from kafka and store them.
My Kafka consists of 1 Kafka Broker, 1 topic and 1 partition. Also I use keys for messages in Kafka.

For my tests I use **Apache Bench**. 
I created a script `test.sh` for my *first test* for run concurrency many requests. I send ever the same json object.

```
ab -s 150 -p post.json -T application/ld+json -c 10000 -n 100000 -rk http://localhost:3000/service_discovery/scorpio > tests/test1.txt &
ab -s 150 -p post.json -T application/ld+json -c 10000 -n 100000 -rk http://localhost:3000/service_discovery/scorpio > tests/test2.txt &
ab -s 150 -p post.json -T application/ld+json -c 10000 -n 100000 -rk http://localhost:3000/service_discovery/scorpio > tests/test3.txt &
ab -s 150 -p post.json -T application/ld+json -c 10000 -n 100000 -rk http://localhost:3000/service_discovery/scorpio > tests/test4.txt &
ab -s 150 -p post.json -T application/ld+json -c 10000 -n 100000 -rk http://localhost:3000/service_discovery/scorpio > tests/test5.txt &
```

First test: 
1)**1 partition** . I make `5.000.000.000` http requests and the end-to-end throughput is `53.22 req/sec`.

Also, I created a script `test2.sh` for my *second test* for run concurrency many requests. I send different json objects with different key and I checked that every object stored at different partition.

```
ab -s 180 -p request_post/post.json -T application/ld+json -c 10000 -n 100000 -rk http://localhost:3000/service_discovery/scorpio > tests/test1.txt &
ab -s 180 -p request_post/post2.json -T application/ld+json -c 10000 -n 100000 -rk http://localhost:3000/service_discovery/scorpio > tests/test2.txt &
ab -s 180 -p request_post/post3.json -T application/ld+json -c 10000 -n 100000 -rk http://localhost:3000/service_discovery/scorpio > tests/test3.txt &
ab -s 180 -p request_post/post4.json -T application/ld+json -c 10000 -n 100000 -rk http://localhost:3000/service_discovery/scorpio > tests/test4.txt &
ab -s 180 -p request_post/post5.json -T application/ld+json -c 10000 -n 100000 -rk http://localhost:3000/service_discovery/scorpio > tests/test5.txt &
```

Second test:
2) **5 partitions** . I make `5.000.000.000` http requests and the end-to-end throughput is `50.13 req/sec`.

I expected higher throughput in second test.
So the question is : why I don't get better throughput with more partitions?

(if you need more information ask me)

Comment: Quick question, when you added 5 kafka partitions, did you also have 5 consumers consuming the data from the 5 partitions in parallel or not? Also, did you check if your messages were distributed (almost) evenly among the partitions?

Comment: Yes, messages distributed evenly among the partitions. For the first question, I can not answer you exactly. Should I declare 5 threads or shoyld I change something in my code?

Comment: You can simply have 5 instances of your consumer running with the same **consumer group id**. Each instance will get assigned 1 partition and you will effectively achieve parallelism. You should read up on consumer groups in kafka in case you don't already know about them.